# How can I get animated bone's transformation in LibGDX?

Tags: java, 2d, animation, libgdx, character

I am trying to get transformation from a bone, but i can't, I exported just a animated armature with just a bone from blender, then I converted to .g3dj, so I just need the bone transformations so that I can get it value for some effects like moving sprites and other things.

any ways to read just transformation in "render()" method, seems bones animation does not effect on bone's value!
I want to use just openGL ES 1.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally found the solution, it was easy,
I needed to get **AnimationDesc** from AnimationControl's animate method in Show() or Creation function

```
animationDesc = animationCtrl.animate("ArmatureAction", -1, 1f, null, 0.2f);
```

and here I can get the node's that animated and effected by animation

```
animationDesc.animation.nodeAnimations.get(1).node.globalTransform.getRotation;
```

note the "get(1)" here is refer to the second bone from the root.

Comment: How would you get a node with a specific ID?